# Android java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException:

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an `exception` saying `Java URI Syntax Exception "java.io.IOException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Invalid % sequence: %wl in query at index 88:"` when i try to connect from my android application.

It seems to be throwing the `exception` where in the URL it says `"%wl"` and following is the URL. is there a work around for this.

```
http://192.168.111.111:9000/RB/db.svc/upd?LinkId=184617ED1F21&IPs=fe80::1a46:17ff:feed:1f21%wlan0,192.168.1.127,&MNo=0771111111&sPin=000&Status=0
```

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode` to encode url queryString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `%` in your URL the first you need to do is to encode it.

So first you need to replace that `%` with `%25` in your string `....1f21%wlan0...` with `.....1f21%25wlan0....` before connecting.

You can use the following code for encoding the URL in Java

```
String encodedUrl = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(<your_url>,"UTF-8");
```

Have a look at the below links for more information.

[1.How to encode url in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-encode-a-url-string-or-form-parameter-in-java/)

[2.URL encoding character reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

**UPDATE :**

If you don't want to use URL encoder then you can try this out :

```
yourURL.replaceAll("%", "%25");
```

It is fine here to replace a single special character, but it would be a tedious task to do like this if you have many special characters that require proper URL encoding.

Comment: so you mean first to replace and then to encode the url? and when I do it it gives me a malformed url exception

Comment: if your are encoding it with URLEncoder then no need to replace, it will be automatically replaced.

Comment: then there must be some problem with your actual url

Comment: Managed to work it out. I just replaced the "%" with "%25" manually and it worked. did not need to use the URLEncoder at all.

Comment: I replaced "%" with "%25", it worked fine.
This is what i used , [myURL.replaceAll("%", "%25")]. Hope, it will be useful for someone. Thanks